# How do i know which url a packet is going to or coming from in python

Tags: python, networking, scapy, packets

Below is an example of the packets I'm getting:-

```
---------------------------------Packet----------------------------------------
Destination MAC : 88:ae:1d:ab:11:95 Source MAC : d0:d0:fd:f5:74:46 Protocol : 8
Version : 4 IP Header Length : 5 TTL : 53 Protocol : 6 Source Address : 196.45.51.39 Destination Address : 10.0.9.137
Source Port : 3128 Dest Port : 52662 Sequence Number : 623854838 Acknowledgement : 396375922 TCP header length : 5

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: All of the information is there.  Are you asking how to parse the packet text?

Comment: How do I get the URL?

Comment: You have to follow the packet sequence up to the originating request. Use Wireshark to capture HTTP traffic and see how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you can try a reverse DNS lookup:

```
import socket
socket.gethostbyaddr(<IP_ADDRESS>)
```

You have to replace IP_ADDRESS.

But I am not sure if it works, if your provider use NATs.